# Github Messenger

Tags: code-golf, date

**Goal:** This goal to take a string and output how many contributions should be made on which days in order to display a message.

[image]

### Specification

- Input

  - Support letters plus space (i.e. `[A-Za-z ]` )
  - Space is a blank `3X7`
  - The letters are defined in this [5x7 DOT Matrix](https://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/847768/5x7_dot_matrix) font provided below
  - The size of each letter is the minimum bounding rectangle (e.g. `l = 3x7`, `e = 5x5`)
- Coloring

  - There are 5 colors `C0, C1, C2, C3, C4`
  - `CX` requires `Y` contributions with `3X <= y < 3(X+1)`
  - Letters should alternate between `C1` and `C2`
  - Spaces have no color
  - Each letter size should overlap exactly 1 column with adjacent letters
  - If a cell has more than 1 color then use `C3`
- Dot Matrix

  - The dot matrix is Github's contribution history graph
  - If today is Monday, May 1st, 2017:

```
 4-30    5-07    5-15
[5-01]   5-08    5-16
 5-02    5-09     .
 5-03    5-10     .
 5-04    5-12     .
 5-05    5-13    
 5-06    5-14
```

- Output

  - Flexible on how this is given
  - `(x, y)` pairs
  - `x` is a date greater than or equal to the current date
  - `y` is the number of contributions to be made on the date, `x`
  - Should be in chronological order (so I can fill in my calendar)
  - If for each date, `x`, the given `y` contributions are made, the input message should show up on the Github graph (with correct coloring)
  - The first date should the earliest possible
- Scoring

  - Shortest program/function in bytes wins

---

## Alphabet

Created by sylvan.black under [CC](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

[image]
[image]

---

## Test Cases

For these test cases, assume the current date is May 25th, 2017.

```
Input -> Output
-----    ------
l        5-28-17, 3
         6-3-17, 3
         6-4-17, 3
         6-5-17, 3
         6-6-17, 3
         6-7-17, 3
         6-8-17, 3
         6-9-17, 3
         6-10-17, 3
         6-17-17, 3

He       5-28-17, 3
         5-29-17, 3
         5-30-17, 3
         5-31-17, 3
         6-1-17, 3
         6-2-17, 3
         6-3-17, 3
         6-7-17, 3
         6-14-17, 3
         6-21-17, 3
         6-25-17, 3
         6-26-17, 3
         6-27-17, 3
         6-28-17, 9
         6-29-17, 9
         6-30-17, 9
         7-1-17, 3
         7-4-17, 6
         7-6-17, 6
         7-8-17, 6
         7-11-17, 6
         7-13-17, 6
         7-15-17, 6
         7-18-17, 6
         7-20-17, 6
         7-22-17, 6
         7-26-17, 6
         7-27-17, 6

o W      5-31-17, 3
         6-1-17, 3
         6-2-17, 3
         6-6-17, 3
         6-10-17, 3
         6-13-17, 3
         6-17-17, 3
         6-20-17, 3
         6-24-17, 3
         6-28-17, 3
         6-29-17, 3
         6-30-17, 3
         7-9-17, 6
         7-10-17, 6
         7-11-17, 6
         7-12-17, 6
         7-13-17, 6
         7-14-17, 6
         7-22-17, 6
         7-26-17, 6
         7-27-17, 6
         7-28-17, 6
         8-5-17, 6
         8-6-17, 6
         8-7-17, 6
         8-8-17, 6
         8-9-17, 6
         8-10-17, 6
         8-11-17, 6
```

Comment: Is C4 ever used?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman It is not, but I included it to avoid confusion because Github displays 5 colors in the legend.

Comment: How strict/loose are you on date output format?

Comment: @StephenS It is flexible, as long as it is human readable (e.g. `May 20th, 2017: 3`, `(3,"20/5/17")` )

Comment: Where did you find that contribution table?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It is on the Overview tab of a [user's profile](https://github.com/NonlinearFruit), beneath their pinned repos.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer If you meant this specific "Hello World" example, I took a screen shot and doctored it.

Comment: @NonlinearFruit Oh I knew it why did everyone think of something else...

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 743 bytes

```js
s=>(n=y=>d.setDate(d.getDate()+y),d=new Date,(h=d.getDay())&&n(7-h),r={},i=0,[...s].map(c=>{c<"!"?n(14):([...parseInt("jn4x733nx8gjw6nhricv6nx8dpz2vilui81vikl7b4nhridnzvgc1svznx8dji8g16fkg0vgc6341vg38oe9vh669ofvgm1dvjnhricvyvikl7aonhrjrjxvikmm29m0rqqp2nqmi6o0vbnf6dav2t14e4vbnjqpqs0g34o3tlqqwdso43oixtg1uyt8vvgddxn2hizrn2ahizrmdbhj4suq4gtytq8wgshvtzyvgc4mq7gzhwhz4g15ymf4vg72q9snx7r2f4jmffjm7jm5gavjhizrn2mjmkh3wogsgmianjm5gavcgwxpc3mhvni2kijhgqujjj8mcsgsjhgslnihw2cx75iqyv1cuhwdrh5d".substr((c.charCodeAt()-(c>"`"?71:65))*7,7),36).toString(2).slice(1).replace(/(0{7})+$/,"")].map(b=>(+b&&(r[+d]=r[+d]?9:i%2?6:3),n(1))),i++,n(-7))}),Object.keys(r).map(k=>[k,r[k]]).sort((i,j)=>i[0]-j[0]>0?1:-1).map(i=>[(new Date(+i[0])+"").slice(4,15),i[1]]))
```

Output is an array of 2-item arrays in the form `[dateString, contribs]`. The snippet below shows how that can be formatted into being more readable.

### Un-Golfed

```js
s=>(
    n=y=>d.setDate(d.getDate()+y),
    d=new Date,
    (h=d.getDay()) && n(7-h),
    r={},
    i=0,
    [...s].map(c=>{
        c<"!" ? n(14) : (
            [...parseInt("<...>".substr((c.charCodeAt()-(c>"`"?71:65))*7,7),36).toString(2).slice(1).replace(/(0{7})+$/,"")].map(b=>(
                +b && (r[+d] = r[+d] ? 9 : i%2?6:3),
                n(1)
            )),
            i++,
            n(-7)
        )
    }),
    Object.keys(r)
        .map(k=>[k,r[k]])
        .sort((i,j)=>i[0]-j[0] > 0 ? 1 : -1)
        .map(i => [ (new Date(+i[0])+"").slice(4,15), i[1] ])
)
```

Where `<...>` represents the 364-byte string of characters that I created to encode each letter's dot matrix form.

### Explanation

The encoded string:

```
jn4x733nx8gjw6nhricv6nx8dpz2vilui81vikl7b4nhridnzvgc1svznx8dji8g16fkg0vgc6341vg38oe9vh669ofvgm1dvjnhricvyvikl7aonhrjrjxvikmm29m0rqqp2nqmi6o0vbnf6dav2t14e4vbnjqpqs0g34o3tlqqwdso43oixtg1uyt8vvgddxn2hizrn2ahizrmdbhj4suq4gtytq8wgshvtzyvgc4mq7gzhwhz4g15ymf4vg72q9snx7r2f4jmffjm7jm5gavjhizrn2mjmkh3wogsgmianjm5gavcgwxpc3mhvni2kijhgqujjj8mcsgsjhgslnihw2cx75iqyv1cuhwdrh5d
```

Each 7 characters is a base-36 encoded binary number that contains the mapping for the character at that index. The binary form always has a leading `1` in order to preserve the leading `0`s. For example, an uppercase `T` maps to `nqmi6o0`, which converts to `1100 00001000 00011111 11100000 01000000`. Skipping the leading 1, each bit is one day. Most numbers have 5 columns/weeks, so the numbers with less than 5 columns have one or two sets of 7 trailing zeros that are later removed before parsing (`.replace(/(0{7})+$/,"")`). This keeps all encoded strings the same length, removing the need for delimiters.

There's probably still more ways to improve upon this, especially with compressing the letter mappings further, so feel free to share any ideas.

Binary format of the letter mappings (JS syntax, prefixed with `0b`), can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jmariner/7caa282497af3e0821e06874237342c9).

### Basic Snippet

```js
f=
s=>(n=y=>d.setDate(d.getDate()+y),d=new Date,(h=d.getDay())&&n(7-h),r={},i=0,[...s].map(c=>{c<"!"?n(14):([...parseInt("jn4x733nx8gjw6nhricv6nx8dpz2vilui81vikl7b4nhridnzvgc1svznx8dji8g16fkg0vgc6341vg38oe9vh669ofvgm1dvjnhricvyvikl7aonhrjrjxvikmm29m0rqqp2nqmi6o0vbnf6dav2t14e4vbnjqpqs0g34o3tlqqwdso43oixtg1uyt8vvgddxn2hizrn2ahizrmdbhj4suq4gtytq8wgshvtzyvgc4mq7gzhwhz4g15ymf4vg72q9snx7r2f4jmffjm7jm5gavjhizrn2mjmkh3wogsgmianjm5gavcgwxpc3mhvni2kijhgqujjj8mcsgsjhgslnihw2cx75iqyv1cuhwdrh5d".substr((c.charCodeAt()-(c>"`"?71:65))*7,7),36).toString(2).slice(1).replace(/(0{7})+$/,"")].map(b=>(+b&&(r[+d]=r[+d]?9:i%2?6:3),n(1))),i++,n(-7))}),Object.keys(r).map(k=>[k,r[k]]).sort((i,j)=>i[0]-j[0]>0?1:-1).map(i=>[(new Date(+i[0])+"").slice(4,15),i[1]]))

I.value="Hello World";
(I.oninput=_=>O.innerHTML = f(I.value).map(e=>e.join(": ")).join("\n"))();
```

```html
<input id="I">
<pre id="O">
```

### [Interactive example](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/vZNZEL/)

Using the library [cal-heatmap](http://cal-heatmap.com/), I created an interactive heatmap of the dates that are output. This was used to test everything while working, and it just looks plain neat.

Comment: The interactive example is really awesome. Nice job!

Comment: Oh god, someone actually did this! Nice!

Comment: Thanks guys! This was a really cool challenge, I wish more people would come attempt it. I've edited my answer to include the dot matrix letters in binary so that others can use the same idea.

Comment: @JustinMariner I popped this onto my profile, hope you don't mind. Nice answer, glad someone completed this challenge :)

Comment: @StephenS Nice, glad you liked it!

Comment: It takes 523 days to spell 'Drink Your Ovaltine'.  Time to get to work..